# Combine data from two different files to make a new one python

Tags: python

I have two tables of data (lists of galaxies) with the same number of elements in each, but different columns. I want to combine the two tables, but when i try (code below) I get either all data from the column in file a but the last value of table b repeated, or vice versa (depending on indentation). How can I get the corresponding values from both tables?

```
a=open('data_tables/ZENS_flags.dat','r')
b=open('IpacTableFromSource2.dat', 'r')
c=open('type_2_new.dat','w')

header1=a.readline()
header1=b.readline()



for line in a:
    line_a = line.strip()
    columns_a = line.split()

    for line in b:
        line_b=line.strip()
        columns_b=line.split()

        c.write(columns_a[4]+"\t"+ columns_a[5]+"\t"+columns_b[12]+"\n")    
c.close()
```

Comment: That repetition is due to nested structure of the program , you need to run the loops in parallel ;) can you provide some sample data in both files which would make the problem clearer ?

Comment: Instead of `for line in b` etc., try `line_b = b.readline().strip()`. Note that on the very first iteration of `for line in a` you're already going through all of `b`, so on successive iterations the `for line in b` block doesn't even run!

Answer (score 0):

If file a and b have the same number, n, of rows. You are now generating a new file with n^2 rows because of the nested loops. If you just erase "for line in b. I think it should work.

```
for line in a:
  line_b = b.readline().strip()
  # the rest is the same but without the second loop.
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
columns_a = a.readline().split()
while columns_a:
    columns_b = b.readline().split()
    c.write(columns_a[4]+"\t"+ columns_a[5]+"\t"+columns_b[12]+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
with open('file1.dat','r') as f:
   cols_a = [line.strip().split() for line in f]

with open('file2.dat', 'r') as f:
   cols_b = [line.strip().split() for line in f]

with open('result.dat','w') as fout:
    '''skip past first line of file'''
    for col_a, col_b in zip(cols_a[1:], cols_b[1:]):
        print col_a
        print col_b
        fout.write(col_a[4]+"\t"+ col_a[5]+"\t"+col_b[12]+"\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [file objects](https://docs.python.org/3.4/glossary.html#term-file-object) created by `open()`, `a` and `b`, keep track of the position where you are in the file. The position is initially at the top of the file and whenever you call `readline()` (for example) the function returns the line it's at and moves its position to the start of the next line. Iterating with `for line in f` is just getting new lines until the position reaches the end of the file.

In this case, you're iterating through the lines left in `a`, and on each line of `a`, you're iterating through the lines left in `b` -- but since the very first iteration of `a` leaves the position of `b` at the end of the file, none of the lines in `a` except for the first one actually write anything!

Instead, you want to read one line at a time from both files, for example:

```
for line in a:
    cols_a = line.strip().split()
    cols_b = b.readline().strip().split()
    c.write(...)
```

Comment: Works like a dream! Thanks!